# JavaScript variable to slider max attribute

Tags: javascript, html, variables, max

Is there a way to put a JavaScript variable into slider's **"max"** attribute value?
For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myVar="20";
</script>


<input id="slider1" name="sliderr" type="range" max="myVar"></input>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
var myVar = 20;
document.getElementById("slider1").max = myVar;
// or
//document.getElementById("slider1").setAttribute("max", myVar);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uE3b9/)

Comment: Your suggestion of `document.getElementById("slider1").setAttribute("max", myVar);` worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**html**

```
<input id="slider1" name="sliderr" type="range" max="myVar"></input>
```

**js**

```
document.getElementById("slider1").setAttribute("max",20);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pb6T4/4/)